# Prove a monotone increasing function is less than another function

Tags: proof-writing, monotone-functions

The question asks to prove 
$\sqrt{x} < x$ 
for all $x>1$ 
This is for a Foundations of Analysis class.

Comment: $x>1$, then, $x^2>x>1$, and, the function $f(y)=\sqrt{y}$ is monotone increasing. Thus, $\sqrt{x^2}>\sqrt{x}>1$ and $x$ in this case is always positive. By this, we can write $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ and, then, $x>\sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}>1\sqrt{x}$ iff $(\sqrt{x}-1)\sqrt{x}>0$.

Since $\sqrt{x}>1$, this is true by closure of the positive reals.

Comment: Why $\sqrt{x}>1$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses squareroot is strictly increasing. squareroot (1) is 1.